# mysql how to update table with same subquery in where clause

Tags: mysql

Following is my query, I am trying to update recods but I get an error:

**you can't specify target table for update in from clause**

```
UPDATE user_payment_info
SET
  ammount='110',
  status='failed',
  transaction_id='0'  
 WHERE
   id=(SELECT id
       FROM user_payment_info
       WHERE cust_id='771'
       ORDER BY id DESC
       LIMIT 1)
```

how can update record with getting id from same table

how can i resolve these mysql error

> you can't specify target table for update in from clause

can some body help me to do these.

Comment: Don't use `order by` in subquery

Comment: @Saty i also try to remove order by but i won't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
UPDATE user_payment_info AS t1
INNER JOIN 
(
       SELECT MAX(id) AS MaxId
       FROM user_payment_info
       WHERE cust_id='771'
) AS t2 ON t1.id = t2.MaxId
SET t1.ammount='110',
    t1.status='failed',
    t1.transaction_id='0';
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to use a subquery, you could use an UPDATE query with order by and LIMIT 1:

```
UPDATE
  user_payment_info
SET
  ammount='110',
  status='failed',
  transaction_id='0'
WHERE
  cust_id='771'
ORDER BY
  id DESC
LIMIT 1
```